# WPF World Editor for my DirectX game engine

Tags: c++, wpf, directx, game-engine

I am working on a small game and game engine in C++ using DirectX. The purpose is educational & recreational.

My next goal is to build a simple world editor that uses the game engine. For this I will need to move the engine into a dll so it can be consumed by the game and/or by the editor. The world editor will be a stand-alone tool and not part of the game. The main purpose of the world editor will be to read in and display my (custom) scene file, and allow me to annotate/modify properties on world objects (meshes), clone objects, pick up and move objects about and drop them, scale objects, etc., and then save out the modified scene so it can later be read by the game.

It has been recommended that I use wxWidgets for the editor. A bit of research makes me feel that wxWidgets is a bit old and clunky, though I am sure very fine GUIs can be written using it. It's just a steep learning curve that I don't look forward to. I have gotten the samples to build and run, but it was a headache.

A little more research and I find that I can integrate DirectX into a WPF app using a D3DImage. I have done a little with WPF and do not find it too intimidating and there are plenty of good books available (there is only one old one for wxWidgets), as well as scads of information on the web. I have gotten the rotating triangle example working and it seemed pretty straightforward.

So my question is:

Will WPF allow me to build a decent little world editor app that re-uses my game engine?

My game engine currently uses RawInput for mouse and keyboard; how will this work with WPF?

How does WPF affect my message pump?

It looks like I will have to write a lot of functions (facade pattern?) to allow WPF to interact with my game engine. Is there an easy way to factor this out so it doesn't get compiled into the game?

Any other tips or ideas on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Should I also be using SlimDx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper class that exposes certain functionality of your game.

For example. This function is in my c++ game engine editor wrapper.

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void SetPlayerPos(int id, const float x, const float y, const float z);
```

Then in your c# wpf application you can create a static class allowing you to use those functions

```
[DllImport(editorDllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetPlayerPos(int id, float x, float y, float z);
```

You will have to have functions for your basic functionality of the game engine through the dll.
things like

EditorMain
RenderFrame / Update
DXShutdown

So then you can call editormain in your wpf app constructor

```
System.IntPtr hInstance = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(this.GetType().Module);
IntPtr hwnd = this.DisplayPanel.Handle;
NativeMethods.EditorMain(hInstance, IntPtr.Zero, hwnd, 1, this.DisplayPanel.Width, this.DisplayPanel.Height);
```

You will need to create a message filter class and initialize it in the constructor as well

```
m_messageFilter = new MessageHandler(this.Handle, this.DisplayPanel.Handle, this);
```

here's how your message filter class could look

```
public class MessageHandler : IMessageFilter 
{
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;


    IntPtr m_formHandle;
    IntPtr m_displayPanelHandle;
    EngineDisplayForm m_parent;

    public MessageHandler( IntPtr formHandle, IntPtr displayPanelHandle, EngineDisplayForm parent )
    {
        m_formHandle = formHandle;
        m_displayPanelHandle = displayPanelHandle;
        m_parent = parent;
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.HWnd == m_displayPanelHandle || m.HWnd == m_formHandle)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                    {
                        NativeMethods.WndProc(m_displayPanelHandle, m.Msg, m.WParam.ToInt32(), m.LParam.ToInt32());
                        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP)
                        {
                            m_parent.SelectActor();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Render the scene
            NativeMethods.RenderFrame();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

for doing win forms and wpf interop look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742474.aspx

Comment: very thorough answer, thank you! I really appreciate the code, I think I could get a start on this now :)